# C++: Static analysis tools that will warn of missing headers

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14, static-analysis

I am compiling a large project for several platforms using GCC and Clang. The issue I have is that I do all of the bug fixing and testing on one platform (Ubuntu 18.04), and even run static tools like `cppcheck` and `clang-tidy` to find bugs. As part of the bug fixing, I even try to compile with several compilers on Ubuntu to make sure that the code is ready to ship.

However, several times I have run across the problem where a developer on another system can't compile the update due to a simple missing include.

A recent example is where we introduced some new functionality which was heavily tested in GCC and Clang on Ubuntu. Then a dev on MacOS got some compiler errors which turned out to be due to a missing `#include <array>` in one file, and missing `#include <sstream>` in another. I mean, when you look at the offending files, they were indeed using `arrays` and `stringstreams`, so I get it. But I am just surprised that the static tools didn't catch those errors.

So how do I solve this problem? They definitely are programming errors, not compiler bugs since it was obvious that I should have included the files.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [include-what-you-use](https://include-what-you-use.org/). From their docs:

> "Include what you use" means this: for every symbol (type, function variable, or macro) that you use in `foo.cc`, either `foo.cc` or `foo.h` should `#include` a `.h` file that exports the declaration of that symbol.

Compiling it yourself isn't trivial as the inner workings of this tool is tightly coupled to the Llvm internals. But you might be lucky to find a pre-built package in your distro. Still, once you get it running, it's not a silver bullet. The problem it tries to solve is hard, there might be false positives etc.

Comment: More from their docs: *"This is alpha quality software -- at best (as of July 2018)."* Last time I've checked this tool it was not suitable for any kind of real world project: adding implementation detail headers, wrong include paths, random include order, dying on circular includes. Even worse than clang format.

Comment: Well, maybe still the best we've got at this point?